# Unable to import module when developing a python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging

My project structure is:

```
APP(dir)

  app(dir)

     model(dir)

        metric_data.py

     __init__.py

     app.py

  setup.py
```

When I'm running `app.py` with import statement of

```py
from model.metric_data import MetricData
```

`MetricData` is a class, I'm able to successfully run the application retrieving data from `metric_data.py` file. But when I build it as a package and then try importing package app

```py
from model.metric_data import MetricData
```

this statement is failing. Can anyone help me with the issue

here, I looked on the relative import part and tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: I have gone through this and tried too but somehow was not able to get it done correctly.

Comment: What about this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268607/issue-with-find-in-setup-cfg-modules-are-not-seen-in-path/70567192#70567192

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a `__init__.py` file in the model directory.

Comment: I have __init__.py inside model directory, I have one more file prac.py inside my app dir which I imported using (from .prac import func) and it worked but how do we do it for file residing inside model dir here

Comment: this is my setup.py                                                                                                                               from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="app",
    version="0.1",
    description="some descr",
    # license='',
    # url=' ',
    packages=["app"],
    author="Nishant Chaubey",
    author_email="nchaubey@gmail.com",
    install_requires=[],
)

Comment: do I need to add anything in setup.py

Comment: @NishantChaubey Maybe you could have a check with your current work directory. If you  use `from model.metric_data import MetricData`, your work directory must be `app`, otherwise `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxx'` will occur.

Comment: You also could put your error logs up for troubleshooting.

Comment: I figured it out, I had to add app.model too as package in setup py and it worked, thanks to all.